# wifi slow and unstable with iwlwifi

Tags: wifi, drivers, networkmanager, nixos, iwlwifi

I have a Thinkpad P50 with NixOs (using the hardware config from https://github.com/NixOS/nixos-hardware, which includes unfree drivers).

I noticed that when using a wireless network it is usually by a lot slower than other devices connected to the same network, and many times I need to manually reconnect, otherwise the connection is as blocked.

I use NetworkManager.

I don't known how to start debugging this.

```
$ lspci -k
...
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0130
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
...
```

**UPDATE**

```
$ ip link show
...
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
...
```

Comment: Does `ip link show` tell you your WiFi MTU is 1500. For WiFi it shoild be 1492. `sudo ip link set dev yourdevice mtu 1492`. Read `man ip ip-link`.

Comment: It was indeed 1500, but after changing it to 1492 nothing changes (I disconnected and reconnected to be sure it was applied)